# Axios post is not a function

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I am getting error when I call axios.post and immediately catch error: [(0 , _dbExpress.default)(...).post is not a function]

```
const signup = dispatch => async ({email, password, username}) => {
        try {
            const response = await dbExpress().post('/signup', {email, password, username});
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            dispatch({type: 'signin', payload: response.data.token});
            navigate('mainFlow');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong with sign up'});
        }
    };
```

Here is my axios interceptors

```
dbExpress.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log("*** inside api")
        if (token) {
            console.log("*** token exist")
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (err)=>{
        console.log("*** reject " +  err.message);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

export default dbExpress;
```

Server works perfectly when I test using postman so it can't be the server side problem.

The version of expo and axios as below:

```
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"expo": "~45.0.0",
```

I not sure where cause the error as these code works on my other project (same version of expo and axios).
If anyone know the issue please help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hry to replace

```
const response = await dbExpress().post('/signup', {email, password, username});
```

with

```
const response = dbExpress.post('/signup', {email, password, username});
```

As far as we can see, your dbExpress exports an axios instance, not a promise